# C# parallelism in LINQ

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I would like to know if this is a safe way of calculating `x` in the code below.

```
public static IEnumerable<Object> Parse(Object obj, ref int x)
{
    x += 10;
    return new List<Object>();
}

public static void Query(List<Object> obj)
{
    int x = 0;

    var result = obj
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(o => Parse(o, ref x))
        .Aggregate((a, b) => a.Concat(b));
}
```

This is a shortened version of my code. I want the `x` to be some kind of a `static counter for all parallel executions of Parse`. I hope this is not confusing.

Comment: Are you sure you really need it?  What do you need it for?  The act of properly synchronizing access to the value means dramatically reduced performance as the operations can no longer work entirely in parallel.

Comment: Also, you should not use `Aggregate/Concat` to transform a sequence of sequences into a flattened sequence.  It results in queries nested N levels deep; it'll very quickly break.  Just use `SelectMany`, it's *specifically* designed to do exactly that.

Comment: I really need it, because in the end I need to check if all the Parse methods have calculated an exact amount of (very complex) objects. And thank you very much for the note about `SelectMany`!

Comment: It sounds like you need to do *something*.  It doesn't sound like you necessarily need to have an integer variable shared between the threads.  For example, each method could return an integer representing whatever count this represents, in addition to the sequence of objects, allowing both resulting values to be aggregated together.  That would allow each operation to do its work entirely in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely **not safe**.
You need to use the `Interlocked` class.

```
public static IEnumerable<Object> Parse(Object obj, ref int x)
{
    Interlocked.Add(ref x, 10);
    return new List<Object>();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code has a race condition. Even though variable `x` is passed by reference, it remains the same variable in all concurrent executions, so adding ten to it needs to be atomic.

One way to fix this would be using [`Interlocked.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33821kfh(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `+=`:

```
public static IEnumerable<Object> Parse(Object obj, ref int x)
{
    Interlocked.Add(ref x, 10);
    return new List<Object>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a different approach to tackle the issue, as suggested earlier introducing a synchronization construct in the Parallel code would impact its working, if you still need it then your original code need something like Interlocked / lock to make it thread safe, however

A better way would be each thread have a local counter and aggregate that at the end, something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int x;
  public object o;
}

public static IEnumerable<MyClass> Parse(Object obj)
{
    MyClass c = new MyClass();
    c.x += 10;
    c.o  = <some new object>
    // Add c to instance of List<MyClass>
    return new List<MyClass>();
}

public static void Query(List<Object> obj)
{          
    var result = obj
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(o => Parse(o))

   // result is of type IEnumerable<MyClass>

   var sum = result.Sum(a=>a.x);

   var aggregate = result.Aggregate((a, b) => a.o.Concat(b.o));
}
```

This is a lock / synchronization free solution which has no performance hit and there's no race condition. Always for threading, try to make things local for a thread and later on apply a function like sum for every individual thread variable.

Comment: Great suggestion for optimization!

Comment: This is very clever! But what do you think about creating tuples and then aggregating them?

Comment: Any DS you like, though need to check the applicability, but keep it thread local, except Concurrent types no DS will be thread safe by default and would either lead to race condition or corruption